# Showing "0" pageview when there is no view

Tags: views

So, I have the following code to display pageview:

```
<div class="mypageview"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pageview', true );?>page view</div>
```

For example, if there is any view, then it will show up as "2 page view."

When there is no view, it just shows up as "page view"

How can I make it so that if there is no view it shows "0" ( 0 Page view)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize your code a bit and localize it. I would add the results from `get_post_meta()` to a variable and then check the returned result an act upon that

You can try something like this

```
<div class="mypageview">
    <?php 
        $views = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pageview', true );
        if ( !$views ) 
            _e( '0 post views' );

        if ( $views == 1 )
            _e( '1 post view' );

        if ( $views > 1 )
            printf(__( ' %s post views' ), $views);
    ?>
</div>
```

### EDIT

On request in comments, you can rewrite the code to the following (*I assume `$output` is defined previously before this code*)

```
$output .= '<div class="mypageview">';
$views = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pageview', true );
if ( !$views ) 
$output .=  __( '0 post views' );

if ( $views == 1 )
$output .= __( '1 post view' );

if ( $views > 1 )
$output .= sprintf(__( ' %s post views' ), $views);
$output .= '</div>';
```

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy:-)

Comment: Please see my edit. Just a request, please add the correct info in your question in order that you get exact answers to your problem :-)

Comment: haha. I actually got it work. I asked prematurely. Sorry about that. Anyway thank you for the help! =)